# Apache Camel: Test if endpoints are up

Tags: apache-camel

Does Camel provide anything out of the box which tells if it is able to connect all endpoints?
These endpoints could be MQ, webservice etc.

If not then I have to write a servlet which will send test request to all the endpoints. I will be using `multicast` or `splitter` for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience Camel will only provide warning logs if a from() endpoint is not available since it is constantly trying to read from them.  Every other endpoint won't be accessed until the exchange tries to use that endpoint.  If your goal is to test if various resources are alive I believe you would need to create your own testing program.  I don't think this will be implemented as a feature because typically applications build in error handling if a resource is down and definte appropriate behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about producers, then no. If your route is sending messages to an `amq` or `http4` endpoint for instance, camel with not automatically send TCP-packets on these connections for monitoring purposes. A common way to handle failure of external endpoints is by using "circuit breakers". Take a look at https://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html. A more robust alternative, imho, is Netflix's [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works).

If you have a polling consumer, say a `from:ftp://..` then the polling consumer will poll messages every n-th millisecond, and you'll get an error if the connection is broken.